# How to resolve AWS Cognito SDK error: "Client <XYZ> is configured for secret but secret was not received?"

Tags: javascript, amazon-cognito

I'm asking this question because I was surprised how little information I could find from Googling. However, I was able to track down what I *think* is the root cause. I'll share it as an answer and see if someone is able to elaborate or provide a better explanation.

So, to clarify, I'm using the AWS JavaScript SDK for Cognito. When I tried some of the standard use cases, I received the following error:

> Client  is configured for secret but secret was not received

What steps can I take to resolve this?

Answer (score 18):

I heard the same issue and I have to delete *App Clients*. Create a new ***App Clients*** and uncheck Generate client secret. Everything worked as expected in my code. [image]

Comment: But, this was supposed to be checked.

Answer (score 13):

If you are not using an SDK to communicate with Cognito, you can include "SECRET_HASH" in "AUTH_PARAMETERS". To compute the "SECRET_HASH", please refer to AWS Docs:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/signing-up-users-in-your-app.html#cognito-user-pools-computing-secret-hash

Here is an example of how to log in users using Python using a client that has both a client ID and client secret:

```py
import json
import requests
import hmac
import hashlib
import base64

client_id = ""
client_secret = ""
cognito_url = ""
username = ""
password = ""

secret_hash = base64.b64encode(hmac.new(bytes(client_secret, 'utf-8'), bytes(
    username + client_id, 'utf-8'), digestmod=hashlib.sha256).digest()).decode()

reqData = {
    "AuthParameters": {
        "USERNAME": username,
        "PASSWORD": password,
        "SECRET_HASH": secret_hash
    },
    "AuthFlow": "USER_PASSWORD_AUTH",
    "ClientId": client_id
}

headers = {
    "X-Amz-Target": 'AWSCognitoIdentityProviderService.InitiateAuth',
    "Content-Type": 'application/x-amz-json-1.1'
}

jsonResponse = requests.post(
    url=cognito_url, data=json.dumps(reqData), headers=headers).json()
    
print(jsonResponse)
```

Comment: very well written , one advice though , for client url , you can write it like : {https://}cognito-idp.{your_aws_region}.amazonaws.com/"

Comment: Surely the accepted answer?

Answer (score 8):

Looking at the NPM package for [Amazon Cognito](https://www.npmjs.com/package/amazon-cognito-identity-js), I notice that:

> When creating the App, the generate client secret box must be unchecked because the JavaScript SDK doesn't support apps that have a client secret.

Checking my app, I found that it had a client secret. I'll try remaking the app without the secret and see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: Does anybody know how does it look like with AWS PHP SDK? I'm using PHP and I'm also getting "Client XYZ is configured for secret but secret was not received"

Answer (score 5):

Even i got the same error , I unchecked the "app client secret" check box during new app client creation in cognito . This solved my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[Mackie Messer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71287987/21482892) is correct in pointing out that Cognito's Javascript SDK doesn't support apps with a client secret. I ran into the same issue but for those interested here is the reason why...

In the context of AWS Cognito, the "client secret" is typically used for server-side authentication to prove the identity of the client making requests. It's considered a sensitive piece of information and is intended to be kept confidential.

When it comes to client-side applications, especially those running in a web browser with JavaScript, it's generally not recommended to use a client secret directly within the application. JavaScript code is inherently visible to users, and embedding a client secret in client-side code could expose it to anyone who happens to be looking.

Cognito's JavaScript SDK allows authentication to be handled on the client side without the need for a client secret. Instead, authentication is typically based on tokens, such as ID tokens and access tokens, which are securely obtained during the authentication process.