# AWS Cognito Javascript API. Not sure what my cognito_url should be set to

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I recently ran into the same issue as discussed in this question: [How to resolve AWS Cognito SDK error: "Client <XYZ> is configured for secret but secret was not received?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71287986/how-to-resolve-aws-cognito-sdk-error-client-xyz-is-configured-for-secret-but)

So I'm trying to go with the bottom answer, which is not using the API but making a request directly. Except I am unsure what the URL is supposed to be.

My first assumption was to use my domain listed in under my User Pool. Basically https://<my_userpool_name>.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com.  But this results in a time out.

My guess is I am using either the incorrect URL, or I need to append something to the end of this.  Amazons documentation gives a few possible choices like /oauth2/authorize under Hosted UI and Federated endpoints, but they seam to be describing ways of sending the user to the AWS hosted sign in page.

Can anyone help clarify what my URL should look like?

Comment: Can you post your JS Code where this issue occurred

Comment: I'm not sure why you need my code. I'm not asking for a fix to the timeout issue. I just want to know what the URL I needed to use was.  If I have the correct URL I can fix the timeout issue my self.

Comment: Also I get asked this almost every time I have a question that is about concepts or something abstract but not directly code related. Is there someplace other than Stackoverflow I should be asking these kinds of questions?

Comment: Reason why ppl ask for code is figure exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: So how is my question unclear to what I am trying to do?  I state I am following another question on here and I need just a little more info.  That question clearly states someone is getting an error when trying to use the Javascript AWS SDK to contact Cognito.  The answer at the bottom states that the person needs to move away from the SDK and make a direct call using a http request.  That http request requires a URL. I just want to know what that URL should be.  Code is not required for this question as anything relevant is already stated in the other question.